# using function autoload register in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
 include("include/config.php");
    include("include/functions.php");
//include("include/functions.php");
include("classes/Database.class.php");
function myAutoload($className)
{
    require_once("classes/{$className}.php");
}
spl_autoload_register('myAutoload');
//make db connection for all files
$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
print_r($db);
$_SESSION['show_records']=10;
```

I am trying to instantiate a new database connection for all files of my plugin , but the database object does not have the database credentials . I am guessing it has something to do with the autoload register . Can someone show me where i am going wrong here ?

my database object returns this:

> Database Object ( [server] => [user] => [pass] => [database] => [pre] => sa_ [record] => Array ( ) [error] => [errno] => 0 [field_table] => [affected_rows] => 0 [link_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [client_info] => 5.6.47 [client_version] => 50647 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.6.47-cll-lve [server_version] => 50647 [stat] => Uptime: 135645 Threads: 8 Questions: 26516818 Slow queries: 2 Opens: 391369 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 5000 Queries per second avg: 195.486 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 316444 [warning_count] => 0 ) [query_id] => 0 )